# why localhost is not loading for vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]
```

when I run the program in chrome its shows the localhost refused to connect.

Comment: So, do you have something running on localhost port 8080? Like, what is that configuration you're showing? what file is that? what does it mean?

Comment: Not sure if vuejs tag is proper. Let's remove it?

Comment: css, javascript, html would also be irrelvant - since the problem is there's no server :p

Comment: on your windows command line run `netstat -ano`. This will list all processes running on your local machine. See if something is running on port 8080. if yes, grab the process id and go into task manager to see what process it is

Answer (score 1):

You should check the following questions:

- Do you have a localhost running? You can find this out by a.E. pinging localhost:8080 in the terminal.
- Did you use a leading slash when importing vue.js into your HTML file or any other resource? This is a common mistake when working with directories in servers.

I wish you much luck

Comment: how to ping localhost:8080?

Comment: when I started my CSS coding this server error started. I import a font and image from chrome...

Comment: @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@800&display=swap');

*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
    background-image: url(https://unsplash.com/photos/A06CvGz10Gg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    


}

Comment: You can ping an URL in different ways. If you're on windows, click into the search bar in the task bar and type cmd, open the program and type "ping localhost:8080". If it fails, you know there is nothing running. On linux, open your terminal and type the same command.

Comment: Answering the clue with CSS: it's very unlikely that CSS is interfering a server connection or similar... maybe you did something else at this time creating the difficulties?

Comment: By the way, from where do you have the code including the localhost address? Maybe you can find more infos about setup (which services you need, whether you need to setup a server or not) at the page you got the code embedding the localhost address

Answer (score 0):

Seems something else is running on 8080.

- on your windows command line run netstat -ano. This will list all processes running on your local machine. See if something is running on port 8080. if yes, grab the process id and go into task manager to see what process it is.

Comment: there is no process in 8080 port :(

Answer (score 0):

In your xampp controller disable MySQL80 inside services. And now start your Apache server and MySQL server.

[image]

[image]

Comment: While it's good that you solved your problem, this answer will likely be of little use to the community. Your question does not include enough context as to what the issue was and this answer not provide any clarity on the matter.